# oai_hss: error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to run `hss` using `oai`. I am using ubuntu 18.04. While running `hss` I got the error:

> ```
> oai_hss: error while loading shared libraries: 
> libmysqlclient.so.20: 
> cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory and can't proceed with the hss.
> ```

can anyone help me to fix the issue please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the `libmysqlclient20` package:

```
sudo apt install libmysqlclient20
```